# ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index in nested loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, nltk, list-comprehension

I'm trying to remove the stopwords in each row of my column. The columns contains rows and the rows since i already `word_tokenized` it with `nltk` then now it's a list which contains tuples. I'm trying to remove the stopwords with this nested list comprehension but it says `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index in nested loop`. How to fix this?

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

data = pd.read_csv(r"D:/python projects/read_files/spam.csv",
                    encoding = "latin-1")

data = data[['v1','v2']]

data = data.rename(columns = {'v1': 'label', 'v2': 'text'})

stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english'))

data['text'] = data['text'].str.lower()
data['new'] = [word_tokenize(row) for row in data['text']]
data['new'] = [word for new in data['new'] for word in new if word not in stopwords]
```

My text data

```
data['text'].head(5)
Out[92]: 
0    go until jurong point, crazy.. available only ...
1                        ok lar... joking wif u oni...
2    free entry in 2 a wkly comp to win fa cup fina...
3    u dun say so early hor... u c already then say...
4    nah i don't think he goes to usf, he lives aro...
Name: text, dtype: object
```

After i `word_tokenized` it with nltk

```
data['new'].head(5)
Out[89]: 
0    [go, until, jurong, point, ,, crazy.., availab...
1             [ok, lar, ..., joking, wif, u, oni, ...]
2    [free, entry, in, 2, a, wkly, comp, to, win, f...
3    [u, dun, say, so, early, hor, ..., u, c, alrea...
4    [nah, i, do, n't, think, he, goes, to, usf, ,,...
Name: new, dtype: object
```

The Traceback

```
runfile('D:/python projects/NLP_nltk_first.py', wdir='D:/python projects')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\python projects\NLP_nltk_first.py", line 36, in <module>
    data['new'] = [new for new in data['new'] for word in new if word not in stopwords]

  File "C:\Users\Ramadhina\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3487, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)

  File "C:\Users\Ramadhina\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3564, in _set_item
    value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)

  File "C:\Users\Ramadhina\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3749, in _sanitize_column
    value = sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)

  File "C:\Users\Ramadhina\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 612, in sanitize_index
    raise ValueError("Length of values does not match length of index")

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Comment: Can you provide example data?

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the error message carefully:

> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

The "values" in this case is the stuff on the right of the `=`:

```py
values = [word for new in data['new'] for word in new if word not in stopwords]
```

The "index" in this case is the row index of the DataFrame:

```py
index = data.index
```

The `index` here always has the same number of rows as the DataFrame itself.

The problem is that `values` is too long for the `index` -- i.e. they are too long for the DataFrame. If you inspect your code this should be immediately obvious. If you still don't see the problem, try this:

```py
data['text_tokenized'] = [word_tokenize(row) for row in data['text']]

values = [word for new in data['text_tokenized'] for word in new if word not in stopwords]

print('N rows:', data.shape[0])
print('N new values:', len(values))
```

As for how to fix the problem -- it depends entirely on what you're trying to achieve. One option is to "explode" the data (also note the use of `.map` instead of a list comprehension):

```py
data['text_tokenized'] = data['text'].map(word_tokenize)

# Flatten the token lists without a nested list comprehension
tokens_flat = data['text_tokenized'].explode()

# Join your labels w/ your flattened tokens, if desired
data_flat = data[['label']].join(tokens_flat)

# Add a 2nd index level to track token appearance order,
# might make your life easier 
data_flat['token_id'] = data.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
data_flat = data_flat.set_index('token_id', append=True)
```

---

As an unrelated tip, you can make your CSV processing more efficient by only loading the columns you need, as follows:

```py
data = pd.read_csv(r"D:/python projects/read_files/spam.csv",
                    encoding="latin-1",
                    usecols=["v1", "v2"])
```

Comment: ah i see, thank you so much for explaining in details and for the very handy tip!

Comment: Hi shadowtalker. I found your answer looking for possible solution to my problem on stackoverflow. I think I have a similar issue (same ValueError in a loop, with a list). However, I tried to explode the columns in my df and I am still not able to fix the issue, even if I understood what is causing it. Could you please have a look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67067204/length-of-values-does-not-match-length-of-index-during-a-for-loop? Many thanks.

Comment: @V_sqrt in general, if something is the wrong length, you need to stop and think about _why_ it's wrong, and moreover think carefully about what you _expected_ to happen. If you have a clear idea of what you actually want to achieve, then you can figure out how to get there. If you are just thrashing around without any goal beyond getting the error messages to go away, then you are not accomplishing anything anyway.