# Length of values does not match length of index during a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a dataset (`df`) like this

```
Name1 Name2 Score
John    NaN  NaN
Patty    NaN  NaN
```

where `Name2` and `Score` are initialized to `NaN`. Some data, like the following

```
name2_list=[[Chris, Luke, Martin], [Martin]]
score_list=[[1,2,4],[3],[]]
```

is generated at each loop from a function. These two lists need to be added to columns `Name2` and `Score` in my `df`, in order to have:

```
Name1 Name2         Score
John    [Chris, Luke, Martin]  [1,2,4]
Patty    [Martin]  [3]
```

Then, since I want to have values and not lists in `Name2` and `Score`, I expand the dataset:

```
Name1 Name2  Name3
John    Chris    1
John    Luke     2
John    Martin   4
Patty   Martin   3
```

My goal is to have all values in `Name2` in `Name1`. However, as I mentioned, I have a function that works as follows: for each element in `Name2`, not in `Name1`, it checks if there are further values. These values generated are similar to those ones seen for `name2_list` and `score_list`.
For example, let's say that, at the second iteration, `Chris` has values generated from the function equal to `[Patty]` and `9`; `Luke` has values `[Martin]` and `1`; `Martin` has values `[Laura]` and `3`. I need then to add these values again to my original `df` in order to have (before exploding)

```
Name1 Name2  Score
John    Chris    1
John    Luke     2
John    Martin   4
Patty   Martin   3
Chris   Patty    9
Luke    Martin   1
Martin  Laura    3
```

Only one value, `Laura`, is not in `Name1` yet, so I will need to run again the function: if the output is already included in `Name1`, then my loop stops and I get the final dataset; otherwise, I will need to rerun the function and see if more loops are required.
To make it shorter in this example, let's suppose that the value of `Laura` after running the function is `John`, `3`. `John` is already in `Name1` so I do not need to rerun the function.

What I have done is the following:

```
name2_list, score_list = [],[]   # Initialize lists. These two lists need to store outputs from my function

name2 = df['name2']              # Append new name2 to this list as I iterate
name1 = df['name1']              # Append new name1 to this list as I iterate
distinct_name1 = set(name1)      # distinct name1. I need this to calculate the difference
diff = set(name2) ^ distinct_name1 # This calculates the difference. I need to iterate until this list is empty, i.e., when len(diff)=0


if df.Name2.isnull().all():  # this condition is to start the process. At the beginning I have only values in Name1. No values in Name2

    if len(diff)>0: # in the example the difference is 2 at the beginning, i.e., John and Patty; at the second round 3 (Chris, Luke, Martin); at the third round is only for Laura. There is no fourth round 
         for x in diff: # I run it first for John, then for Patty
            collected_data = fun(df, diff) # I will explain below what this function does and how it looks like
    
        df = df.apply(pd.Series.explode) # in this step I explode the dataset

        name2 = df['Name2']             # I am updating the list of values in Name2 to calculate the difference after each iteration. 
        name1 = df['Name1']             # I am updating the list of values in Name1 to calculate the difference after each iteration. 
        distinct_name1 = set(name1)    # calculate the new difference
        diff = filter(None, (set(name2) ^ distinct_name1) ) # calculate the new difference. Iterate until this is empty
```

An error occurs when I consider this step `df['Name2'] = name2_list`  in the function:

> ---> 33     df['Name2'] = name2_list

saying:

> ValueError: Length of values (6) does not match length of index (8).

(the values inside the round brackets may be different from those ones that you could get by using this example)

My function currently does not care how many rows are in the dataframe and it is creating new lists of some different length. I would need to find a way to reconcile this. I was debugging and I can confirm that the error comes from `df['Name2'] = name2_list` in the function. I am able to correctly print the list of new name2 values, but not the column.
Maybe, a possible solution could be to build the df once outside of the `for` loop, but I need to explode `df['Name2']` and build lists where to store results from the web.

Comment: What is the `check` variable ? Based on your logic in `fun`, you need to make sure `assert len(df) == len(diff)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not a good idea to use pandas for this kind of problem. If you are fine with plain python for intermediate steps, you could do this:

```
import pandas as pd


def get_links(source_name):
    """Dummy function with data from OP.
    
    Note that it processes one name at a time instead of batch like in OP.
    """
    dummy_output = {
        'John': (
            ['Chris', 'Luke', 'Martin'],
            [1, 2, 4]
        ),
        'Patty': (
            ['Martin'],
            [9]
        ),
        'Chris': (
            ['Patty'],
            [9]
        ),
        'Luke': (
            ['Martin'],
            [1]
        ),
        'Martin': (
            ['Laura'],
            [3]
        ),
        'Laura': (
            ['John'],
            [3]
        )
    }
    target_names, scores = dummy_output.get(source_name, ([], []))

    return [
        {'name1': source_name, 'name2': target_name, 'score': score}
        for target_name, score in zip(target_names, scores)
    ]


todo = ['John', 'Patty']

seen = set(todo)
data = []

while todo:
    source_name = todo.pop(0)  # If you don't care about order can .pop() to get last element (more efficient)
    # get new data
    new_data = get_links(source_name)
    data += new_data

    # add new names to queue if we haven't seen them before
    new_names = set([row['name2'] for row in new_data]).difference(seen)
    seen.update(new_names)
    todo += list(new_names)

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output:

```
    name1   name2  score
0    John   Chris      1
1    John    Luke      2
2    John  Martin      4
3   Patty  Martin      9
4   Chris   Patty      9
5    Luke  Martin      1
6  Martin   Laura      3
7   Laura    John      3
```

Comment: do you have any idea about this ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74201109/looping-failing-check-the-length-of-data-matches-the-length-of-the-index-index